# Why the "vmc services" command only returns one table?

Tags: service, command, cloud-foundry, vmc

In the vmc document from cloudfoundry, it says the "vmc services" command will return two tables, the first tables contains the available service types, and the second table returns the provisioned services instances. But I found with the latest version of vmc, the "vmc services" command only returns one table which contains "provisioned services". It's very in-convenient as I cannot see what kind of services the system can support.

Note: I found the very old version of vmc can list two tables.

Anyone have meet this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the latest version vmc, please use

```
vmc info --services
```

to get all the services available. Use

```
vmc help COMMAND
```

to get the usage of each command.

I believe the CF team is working on refining the document of all these stuff. They should soon make it better.